# Beautiful Soup / Regular Expressions: Extract a portion of text from NavigableString

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm really new to learning python so this could be really obvious, but I have extracted a NavigableString from BeautifulSoup and I need to find data in the string. However, it's not as easy as some of the examples I've seen online.

My end goal is to create a dictionary that looks something like this:

```
dict = {'Fandom':'Undertale (Video Game)', 'Works':15341}
```

Here's are two examples of the strings:

```
<li>
<a class="tag" href="/tags/Undertale%20(Video%20Game)/works">Undertale (Video Game)</a>
          (15341)
      </li>

<a class="tag" href="/tags/Sherlock%20Holmes%20*a*%20Related%20Fandoms/works">Sherlock Holmes &amp; Related Fandoms</a>
          (101015)
      </li>
```

I've already succeeded extracting fandom from the string, but now I need the works count in parenthesis. How would I use Beautiful Soup and/or Regular Expressions to do this?

I also need to do error handling because while a fandom will always be displayed, it may not have a work count next to it.

```
<li>
<a class="tag" href="/tags/Composer%20-%20Fandom/works">Composer - Fandom</a>
</li>
```

Here's the relevant pieces of code:

```
        for each_f in cate:
            #print(each_f)
            result = each_f.find('a')
            if result !=-1:
                #here is where I grab the Fandom vals
                fandom_name = result.contents
                #print(result.contents)
```

NOTE: I know I'm missing the code to append to the dictionary, I haven't made it that far yet. I'm just trying to get the values to print to the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `dict.fromkeys(('Fandom', 'Works'))` to get :

```
In [17]: dict.fromkeys(('Fandom', 'Works'))
Out[17]: {'Fandom': None, 'Works': None}
```

use `zip` to combines the key with strings in the `li` tag, this will only combines the shortest:

```
zip(('Fandom', 'Works'),li.stripped_strings)

[('Fandom', 'Undertale (Video Game)'), ('Works', '(15341)')]
[('Fandom', 'Sherlock Holmes & Related Fandoms'), ('Works', '(101015)')]
[('Fandom', 'Composer - Fandom')]
```

then we update the `dict` with those data:

```
In [20]: for li in soup.find_all('li'):
    ...:     d = dict.fromkeys(('Fandom', 'Works'))
    ...:     out = zip(('Fandom', 'Works'),li.stripped_strings)
    ...:     d.update(out)
    ...:     print(d)
```

out:

```
{'Works': '(15341)', 'Fandom': 'Undertale (Video Game)'}
{'Works': '(101015)', 'Fandom': 'Sherlock Holmes & Related Fandoms'}
{'Works': None, 'Fandom': 'Composer - Fandom'}
```

Comment: I ended up having to modify this a bit because it didn't like zip as it was. Stripping the strings returned: out = [('F', 'W', u'Undertale (Video Game)'), ('a', 'o', u'(15343)')]. However, it does move me closer to the answer, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`stripped_strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) and unpack the values to get your blocks of text. You can store the results in a `dict`so that you can use them later.

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


example = """<li>
<a class="tag" href="/tags/Undertale%20(Video%20Game)/works">Undertale (Video Game)</a>
      (15341)
  </li>

<li><a class="tag"     href="/tags/Sherlock%20Holmes%20*a*%20Related%20Fandoms/works">Sherlock Holmes &amp; Related Fandoms</a>
      (101015)
  </li>
  <li>
<a class="tag" href="/tags/Composer%20-%20Fandom/works">Composer - Fandom</a>
</li>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(example, "html.parser")
Fandom = {"Fandom" : []}

for li in soup.find_all("li"):
    try:
        fandom, count = li.stripped_strings
        Fandom["Fandom"].append({fandom.strip() : count[1:-1]})
    except:
        fandom = li.text.strip()
        Fandom["Fandom"].append({fandom.strip() : 0})

print (Fandom)
```

This outputs:

> {'Fandom': [{'Undertale (Video Game)': '15341'}, {'Sherlock Holmes & Related Fandoms': '101015'}, {'Composer - Fandom': 0}]}

The try-catch will catch any unpacking that doesn't contains two values: your fandom title and the word count.